# My manager keeps forcing me to be a team lead when I've asked her not to

Tags: teamleader

My manager continuously forces me to run shifts and leaves me alone with one other person when I specifically asked her not to because of my physical and my mental health

Comment: So... whats your question?

Comment: Did you talk to your manager about it? What did they say?

Comment: Sounds frustrating. What sort of work do you do, and where abouts in the world are you?

Comment: Is it a particular person that is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Realistically, as you become more experienced, most employers will expect you to help guide and train other employees. You should probably think long and hard about how to overcome your reluctance to do so; it will handicap your career growth. There is no shame in asking for professional assistance in breaking through personal barriers, and mental health issues such as depression are treatable.

If you really can't be helped, or can't accept help...

You can try asking to transfer to another group whose manager is more willing to let you avoid these responsibilities.

Or you can try looking for a job which doesn't involve these responsibilities. I have to warn you that this requirement may make job hunting hard.

Or you can try to find a consulting position where you are working alone. Which might be your best bet, though consulting has its own stresses and is definitely not a good choice for everyone.

Comment: Yes, "most employers will expect you to help guide and train other employees." But that should come with  a commensurate job title, formal authority and compensation, and shouldn't be a freebie.

Comment: Recognition/reward was ***not*** the objection raised here. But: No "freebie", just standard business practice. Promotion often recognizes the work you have already been doing successfully, rather than being granted in the hope you can step up. And we don't know that they s individual isn't already at a rank and pay band where this is expected to be part of their role. If you don't do what your manager legitimately needs done and asks you to do, that is likely to have career-limiting consequences.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky one.

On the one-hand, this would be something you could raise with HR - about an unreasonable delegation of responsibilities.

However, on the flip-side - if you have seniority (e.g. length of service served/experience) etc. then it is a reasonable request that if the Manager's attention(s) are required elsewhere, that as the next most senior or responsible person, you handle what needs to be done.

Without knowing the frequency, degree and reasons for these delegations, it's difficult for us to recommend a next course of action:

If this is being done only when the company has a requirement for the Manager to otherwise be occupied and there is a very clear disparity in terms of experience between you and your co-worker, it may be that there isn't much you can do.

If, however, it's being done so the Manager can sit in their office and watch YouTube or otherwise shirk their duties by delegating it to you, then you might have grounds to raise it to HR.